# JComponent: how to do a repaint in the most correct way?

Tags: java, swing

We have following methods:

- `java.awt.Component#repaint()`

  > This is old method that repaints in AWT. It does not repaint immediately, it schedules repaint.
- `javax.swing.JComponent#repaint(long, int, int, int, int)`

  > This is new swing method that repaints in Swing. It schedules repaint with the RepaintManager.

Both of them may be invoked from a user thread as well as from the event-dispatching-thread.

Which of them is the most correct way to repaint Swing component (`JComponent`)?

Answer (score 0):

> Which of them is the most correct way to repaint Swing component (JComponent)?

Both of them are the correct way.

Swing components always invoke `repaint()` when you change a property of the component by using setText(), setForeground(), setBackground() etc. This will make sure the entire component is repainted.

The `repaint(...)` method can be invoked if you need to optimize painting of the component. If you have a large component and only a small part of the component changes you can use this method. However, I would recommend you don't worry about this. Swing painting is double buffered and efficient so there is rarely a case when you need to optimize the painting code.